# What does this Perl function do?

Tags: perl

I am just trying to learn some Perl, so I am going through one function just to get grip on the language. Could somebody explain to me what this function is doing exactly?

```
#! /usr/bin/perl 
use strict; 

my %hash; 

&Parse('first.txt'); 
&Parse('second.txt'); 

my $outputpath = 'output.txt'; 
unlink ($outputpath); 
open (OUTPUT, ">>$outputpath") || die "Failed to open OUTPUT ($outputpath) - $!"; 
print OUTPUT "$_ \t" . join("\t", @{$hash{$_}}) . "\n" foreach (sort keys %hash); 
close (OUTPUT) || die "Failed to close OUTPUT ($outputpath) - $!"; 

sub Parse { 
    my $inputpath = shift; 
    open (INPUT, "<$inputpath") || die "Failed to open INPUT ($inputpath) - $!"; 
    while (<INPUT>) { 
        chomp; 
        my @row = split(/\t/, $_); 
        my $col1 = $row[0]; 
        shift @row; 
        push(@{$hash{$col1}}, @row); 
    } 
    close (INPUT) || die "Failed to close INPUT ($inputpath) - $!"; 
    return 1; 
}
```

I am more interested in `shift` and `push` and `chomp`.

Comment: http://p3rl.org/shift http://p3rl.org/push http://p3rl.org/chomp

Comment: @Svante: to avoid unhelpful comments as the one you posted above. How does this help the OP? Maybe he cannot find the Manual, or can't find where in the manual to look.

Comment: I guess one can derive from that which four letters I had posted.  :)

Comment: @Konerak: in that case he should have asked "where can I findPerl documentation", not "explain this program to me". Svante's post was not unhelpful at all, it drives directly to the root issue.

Comment: I respectfully disagree. "How does 'command' work" could maybe be answered with a 'RTFM' (but even then, a link to the manual or perldoc or ... would be better). "How does this piece of code work" is not really in the manual - maybe he lacks the skills to put it all together from the individual comments. But hey, do unto others ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Edit: You posted some extra code, I'll comment that as well.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl 
#The first line (has to be first, hence this comment comes after) allows the linux shell to know 
#this is a perl program, and to call perl to execute it.

#use strict: allow stricter checking of perl syntax. You should always do this.
use strict; 

#declare a global variable called hash - not a very good name...
my %hash; 

#call the method with 'first.txt' as argument
&Parse('first.txt'); 
&Parse('second.txt');  #same thing, different parameter


my $outputpath = 'output.txt'; 

#destroy the file declared above if it exists
unlink ($outputpath); 

# open the file for append (could simple have opened for output and not used the unlink above...)
open (OUTPUT, ">>$outputpath") || die "Failed to open OUTPUT ($outputpath) - $!"; 

#print a line to output 
#the line comes from a foreach loop
#the foreach loop runs over the hash, sorted by key
#each hash entry contains an array, this array is converted by a string using the JOIN function
# the join function will paste the elements of the array into a string, seperated by a tab
print OUTPUT "$_ \t" . join("\t", @{$hash{$_}}) . "\n" foreach (sort keys %hash); 

#Close the outputfile
close (OUTPUT) || die "Failed to close OUTPUT ($outputpath) - $!";
```

This program was probably written some time ago - Modern Perl looks a bit different and has a few best practices that are not here yet.

Don't use this as an example on how to write Perl. Maybe [Ether](https://stackoverflow.com/users/40468/ether) will rewrite this for you, if you smile nicely :)

```
#declare a sub
sub Parse { 
    # the parameters given to a sub are stored in @_. 
    #shift without arguments takes the first element from @_
    my $inputpath = shift; 
    #opens the file "inputpath" into fileglob INPUT. 
    #If this fails, quit with an error message
    open (INPUT, "<$inputpath") || die "Failed to open INPUT ($inputpath) - $!"; 

    #loop over the file one line at the time, putting each line in $_
    while (<INPUT>) { 

        #chop = remove last character. chomp = remove last character if it is a CRLF. 
        #Without arguments, works on $_ 
        chomp; 

        #split the $_ variable (containing the row) 
        #into an array based on the tab character
        my @row = split(/\t/, $_); 

        # take the first element into col1
        my $col1 = $row[0]; 

        # shift it (remove the first element)
        shift @row; 

        # actually both rows above can be just written as one statement:
        my $col1 = shift @row;

        #the $hash variable is probably a global hashref defined somewhere above...
        #the $hash hashref now contains a bucket named with the 'col1' value
        # the value of that bucket is the array of the row we just read
        push(@{$hash{$col1}}, @row); 

        # end the while loop
    } 

    #close the file or die
    close (INPUT) || die "Failed to close INPUT ($inputpath) - $!"; 

    #end the method
    return 1; 
}
```

Comment: Now i have pasted the complete program.could you also explain about the print statement ?

Answer (score 3):

Look up the [documentation](http://perldoc.perl.org/).

- Hashes: [perldata](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldata.html)
- [shift](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/shift.html)
- [chomp](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/chomp.html)

Answer (score 2):

If you have a sane perl installation the following command line commands will help:

```
perldoc -f shift
perldoc -f push
perldoc -f chomp
```

You'll also love:

```
perldoc perlfunc
perldoc perlvar
```

Don't miss the `perlvar` part about `$_` or you won't ever get what perl is about.

You'll gradually notice perl is not object oriented, it supports objects, but it's a pretty odd implementation. Perl is more *getting the work done* oriented and the *work* is usually related to the extraction or translation of some kind of data set.

Perl one liners are the most powerful command lines you will ever write:

```
perl -pe 's/(\d*)/$1*10/ge'
```

Check out the `-p`, `-e`, `-n` and `-i` switches in `perldoc perlrun`

(That's one of the main reasons Perl 6 was scheduled as major rewrite, only now it's been in the works since *always* and scheduled to release the day after *Duke Nukem Forever*)

`shift` anyway is like python's `some_array.pop(1)` or javascript's `some_array.shift()`, etc.

`push` is like python's `some_array.append(junk)` or javascript's `some_array.push(more_junk)`, etc.

`chomp` is really peculiar and is actually the cross-platform version of `chop`: it removes end-of-line character from lines that have been read from stdin. It's a kind of an hack to overcome this little diamond operator <> (check `perldoc perlop` - "I/O Operators" section) flaw: diamond reads stdin or a command line file argument line by line, but it doesn't remove the `\n`. (nor the `\r\n`)

`chomp` removes them after that. (`chop` only removes `\n` and leaves `\r` alone.)

Comment: A last word of warning: reading other people's perl  *(or even yours, after a couple of weeks)* can be a *royal pain*, focus on deliberate examples and manuals. Perl documentation is the more extensive I've ever seen.

Comment: no, it's not reading other peoplr's Perl. It's reading Perl by people who don't know how to do software development, more specifically how to write readable code. Said people would write unreadable code in ANY language.

Comment: Sorry man, I've been reading core modules: peer reviewed, well indented, well commented, documented, and unit tested: yet it *still* was a pain.